# A stick is broken in three pieces. Find the probability that the resulting pieces are shorter than a certain length.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

A stick has a length of $5$ units. The stick is then broken at two points chosen at random. To find the probability that all three resulting pieces are shorter than $3$.

---

I tried with complement prob: We can have only one piece $\ge 3$. So I tried to find how many ways we can break the remaining into two parts.

Comment: The number of ways to break the remaining into is infinite. Of course, you can mark the stick with, say, 4999 milliunit marks and declare that only those points will be chosen. Then you can "find how many ways". That will be a decent approximation to the real answer, but it will only be an approximation.

Comment: How exactly was it broken? A. Choose two random points and break the stick at those two points. B. Break the stick at a random point. Break the larger part at a random point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we cut the stick at $x$ and $y$:

[image]

In region A, $y>x+3$, so the middle piece is longer than $3$.
In region B, $x>3$ and $y>3$, so the leftmost piece is longer than $3$.
In region C, $x<2$ and $y<2$, so the rightmost piece is longer than $3$.
In region D, $x>y+3$, so again the middle piece is longer than $3$.

The areas of these four regions add up to $\dfrac{12}{25}$. So the probability that every piece is *shorter* than $3$ is $\dfrac{13}{25}$, as Henry says.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: try a graphic approach. You can plot all possible "breaks" as the square $[0,5]\times[0,5]$. Then, try to think about what the length of the three pieces is for each point in that square, and what condition must be met so that the longest piece is shorter than $3$.

**Hint 2**: It might be easier to look at the triangle $\{(x,y)\in[0,5]\times[0,5]: x \leq y\}$ and then its complement, and examine the condition on each of them separately. Or even just notice that it is enough to examine one of the triangles as the other one is a mirror image of the first.

Comment: I tried to think with the first hint: On the $x$-axis, I take the length of the 1st piece, on the y axis I take the length of the 2nd piece. now the third piece is $5-x-y$.

Comment: Next we should have $x ,y, 5-x-y \le 3$. Am I thinking correctly? But how to proceed then?

Comment: @User8976 No, don't take the length of the pieces on the axis. Instead, take the position of the breaks.

Comment: what you mean by the position of the breaks?

Comment: @User8976 $x$ is the location on the stick where the stick is broken, and $y$ is the second such location.

Comment: So I take $x$ on one axis and $y$ on the other axis. Now the lengths are $x,y-x $ and $5-y$

Comment: @User8976 Well, those are the lengths if $y>x$. But the point is that because both variables, x and y, are uniformly distributed, you only need to find the area of the region in which the lengths of the stick are all shorter than $3$.

Comment: Yes, that I understood..but I am finding difficulty in defining the region whose area I have to find.

Comment: @User8976 Take a couple of points in various parts of the square, and think about what the lengths of the line are if you break in that point. For example, if $x=1, y=3$, then the lengths are $1,2,2$, so that point will certainly be in the region. And if $x=1, y=4.5$, then the lengths are $1, 3.5, 0.5$, so that point is *not* in the region. Think about when the condition breaks.

Comment: So if we take sum of two of the pieces then it must me $\ge 2$ as well as $\le 5$. So the reqd area is between the two strips?

Answer (score 1):

The probability the first piece is too long is the probability both $x$ and $y$ are greater than $3$, which is $\left(\frac{5-3}{5}\right)^2=\frac4{25}$

The probability the central piece is too long is the probability $|x-y|>3$, double the probability $x>y+3$, so also $2\times \frac12 \left(\frac{5-3}{5}\right)\left(\frac{2-0}{5}\right)= \frac4{25}$

The probability the last piece is too long is the probability both $x$ and $y$ are less than $2$, which is also $\left(\frac{2-0}{5}\right)^2=\frac4{25}$

You cannot have more than one of the pieces too long, since $3+3>5$.  So the probability none of the pieces are too long is $1-\frac{12}{25}=\frac{13}{25}$

Answer (score 0):

[image]Lets say that the pieces are $x,y,z$ where $x+y+z =5$.We want to find the cases that all pieces are less than or equal to $3$ , (remember that because of this is continuous probability distribution , it does not matter whether it is $<$ or $\leq$).

Now , lets randomly work over the pieces , we want that $z \leq 3$ and $x+y+z =5$ , to satisfy this condition , when $z \leq 3$ , $x+y \geq2$. So ,we can conclude that if we find the probability that $x+y \geq 2$ , we can find the result , by the way realize that $x \leq5 ,y\leq5$ in our sample set.

Finding the probability is equal to finding the area between the lines $x+y =5$ and $x+y=2$. Then it is equal to $$\frac{5 \times 5}{2} - \frac{2 \times 2}{2} =\frac{21}{2}$$ .Moreover , our sample set is the points where $x+y =5$ , then it is equal to $\frac{5 \times 5}{2}$

Then , the probability is $$\frac{\frac{21}{2}}{\frac{5 \times 5}{2}}= \frac{21}{25}$$

$\mathbf{\text{EDITION:}}$ After we find $x+y \geq 2$ , we must also add the restrictions for $x$ and $y$ such that $x \leq3 ,y\leq3$ , these restrictions will construct two gaps between the lines of $x+y \geq 2$ and $x+y \leq 5$ , the area of each of these gaps is $\frac{2\times2}{2}$ i so we must subtract them from the total. Then , $$\frac{25}{2}-\frac{4}{2}-\frac{4}{2}-\frac{4}{2} = \frac{13}{2}$$

So , $$\frac{\frac{13}{2}}{\frac{25}{2}}= \frac{13}{25}$$

Comment: $\dfrac{21}{25}$ is much too high $-$ it is the probability that the _rightmost_ piece is shorter than three.

Comment: @TonyK thanks , it seems that i forgot to add the restrictions for $x$ and $y$